# sqlall not working returns nothing

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

Hello I am running python manage.py sqlall groups (also tried sql) and when I run this command it simply returns back to command prompt:

```
david@mint-desktop ~/workspace/newapp $ python manage.py sqlall groups 

david@mint-desktop ~/workspace/newapp $
```

I have ran the commands syncdb, validate, inspectdb all with success and this command seems not to error out but doesnt return any DDL.  I am under the impression this command creates the DLL for my models for mysql.  Am I missing a step? I tried building my models in mysql and was able to access them after manually building the tables. Thanks!

Comment: Can we see the models.py of your groups app?

Comment: Well I rewrote my model just now and it worked so I had something wrong. I will try and recreate it real quick and figure out what the issue was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Django's admin sometimes drops a model when it encounters an error, instead of reporting it.

In my experience, using the "south" extension to manage my models helps with that problem.
(It's also a good idea in general, if you ever need to change the model …)